# Comparar elementos de una misma lista con bucle for

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, bucle-for

He creado un bucle que compara un par de coordenadas (X1, Y1), con otro par (X2, Y2) y me devuelve una lista con los pares en común.

```
#                Pares   X1      Y1      X2      Y2
ingreso_datos = [[ 1,     0,     0,      0,      7],
                 [ 2,    29,     0,     29,      7],
                 [ 3,     0,     7,   14.5,   8.15], 
                 [ 4,  14.5,  8.15,     29,      7]] 
pares =  []
for i in range(len(ingreso_datos)):
    for j in range(len(ingreso_datos)):
        if ingreso_datos[i][1] == ingreso_datos[j][3] and ingreso_datos[i][2] == ingreso_datos[j][4]:
            pares.append([ingreso_datos[i][0], ingreso_datos[j][0]])
print(pares)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Problema**

Ahora busco comparar un par de coordenadas (X2, Y2) con todos los (X2_i, Y2_i) de esa misma columna, ya que al hacerlo **además de los pares comunes obtenidos con el anterior bucle [3,1] y [4,3] obtendría el par común [2, 4],** he intentado lo siguiente:

```
for i in range(len(ingreso_datos)):
    for j in range(len(ingreso_datos)-1):
        if ingreso_datos[i][3] == ingreso_datos[j][3] and ingreso_datos[i][4] == ingreso_datos[j][4]:
            pares.append([ingreso_datos[i][0], ingreso_datos[j][0]])
```

Pero obtengo pares que no deberían corresponder, lo que busco en este nuevo bucle es que haga algo así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco mucho la ayuda, saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La idea no difiere mucho de lo que ya haces cuando comparas las dos "columnas" de coordenadas. Solo que en éste caso **el segundo ciclo solo debe iterar desde el índice siguiente al generado por el primer `for` en esa iteración hasta el final**. De ésta forma evitas que se realicen comparaciones ya efectuadas en iteraciones previas del primer ciclo:

```
len_datos = len(ingreso_datos)
for i in range(len_datos):
    for j in range(i + 1, len_datos):
        if (ingreso_datos[i][3] == ingreso_datos[j][3] and
            ingreso_datos[i][4] == ingreso_datos[j][4]
            ):
            pares.append([ingreso_datos[i][0], ingreso_datos[j][0]])
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por el aporte @FJSevilla.